# Any way to list the BIOS drive numbers in real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bios, real-mode

Is there any way to list the BIOS drive indexes in real mode (E.g. 0x80, 0x81 ...)?

I did not find any interrupt that is in charge of listing drive numbers!!

Comment: I think you can find the number of hard drives at 40:75 in the the [BIOS Data Area](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html).  While I don't 'know' that they will be referenced sequentially, I'd expect so.  You might also look at int 21h 0E, which returns "the highest drive present." Alternately, there's calling int 13h/08 and incrementing the drive number until you get an error.  I'm pretty sure DOS maxed out at 26 drives (including floppies), so this loop wouldn't run very long.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWohlferd. I tried what you have said. But it seems that something wrong is going with me, maybe there is something I have missed. 40:75 returned one drive, 13/08 returned one drive on dl. In addition I tried what you said: a loop on 13/08 it found just 0x80. However, I am booting from USB drive and the computer already have a harddisk which is the second choice in BIOS. Please note that without the USB stick, the computer is working properly. In addition, the USB stick is working on another computer. I tried everything, do you have any theoretical idea, or I send another SO?

Comment: Would USB show up as a "hard drive?"  It's removable, so maybe it's seen as a floppy?

Comment: You are right @DavidWohlferd, I have never knew about considering removable media as floppy drive from the BIOS point of view. The USB stick drive's number is zero while the HDD drive's number is 0x80. Thanks a lot. Btw, you can offer me an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: When booting the BIOS passes the drive number of the boot device in DL to the boot sector code. If you're using your own boot sector code then you should use this number to determine the boot device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to 'list' the available bios drives in real mode.

However, there are some things that might help:

- The number of hard drives is stored at `40:75` in the the [BIOS Data Area](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html).  While I don't 'know' that drive numbers are assigned sequentially, I'd expect them to be.  If so, the list of hard drives would run from 0x80 to 0x80 + (40:75 - 1) (although conceivably there could be 0 hard drives, so 0x80 might not be valid either).
- There is also `int 21h function 0E` [(select default drive)](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0e), which returns "the highest drive present."  Without checking, I'm guessing this is related to [LastDrive](http://www.easydos.com/lastdrive.html), but it might be useful.
- And finally there's `int 13h function 08` [(read drive parameters)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D08h:_Read_Drive_Parameters) and incrementing the drive number until you get an error. I'm pretty sure DOS maxed out at 26 drives (including hard disks, cds, floppies, etc), so this loop wouldn't run very long.

Note that for bios functions, hard drives typically have the most significant bit set.  So hard drive #0 is referred to as 0x80, #1 is 0x81, etc.  Floppy drives don't have this bit set and so count from 0.

By the time USB drives came along, I had stopped using DOS, so I'm not sure whether they appear as hard drives or floppies.  Since they are removable, I wouldn't expect them to be listed as hard drives, but it may depend on the driver you use.

Comment: If you're *booting* from USB, then you're almost certainly doing it via the BIOS's floppy drive emulation mode. If you're booted from some other drive and running under DOS, then it will entirely depend upon the driver.

Comment: DOS function 0Eh deals with logical drives, many of which could be on the same physical drive. The BIOS drive numbers all indicate physical drives.

Comment: On my *true* DOS computer, the USB drive is treated as a hard disk by DOS and BIOS alike.